# Django raise ValidationException on id field when testing abstract model

Tags: django, mongodb, abstract-class

I have an abstract django model like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

When testing this class using following code:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db import models
from core.models import BaseModel

class BaseModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        class SimpleClass(BaseModel):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

        simple = SimpleClass(name="test")
        simple.save()
        simple.full_clean()
        ...
```

I get following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'id': ['“6072d8ce3c23022d0694ae8e” value must be an integer.']}
```

I'm using `mongodb` as my database. There is no such error when I delete `abstract = True`.

Comment: Overriding id to be uuid solved the problem anyway!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB isn't supported by Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/

Also testing of the django internals aren't necessary. With the code provided you are not actually testing your class since you are creating a new one in the test method. I don't understand the calling of `full_clean` either.

You may check this out: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: This is a minimal question to show the problem and so code may seem dumb! But I need full_clean() in a real scenario. I also need to test the logic of my abstract class and this is the best thing I could come up with! Also I'm new to django and there maybe far better ways of doing what I want to do!

Comment: I see, It feels to me that you are using the wrong methods for it but there is no way for me to know this for certain. I showed you that mongodb isn't supported and these type of errors are not caused by your logic but rather the django's internals. You should only test the custom properties and methods in your models, also import the class in the tests from your models do not create the entire class there.